# Using MS Project VB Macro for Obtaining Custom Field Value at Assignment Level

Tags: vba, ms-project

In our Project Enterprise installation there is a task level custom field called **Billing Rate**, but in the plan it is populated at the assignment level, like the following:

```
Task Name         Billing Rate
==========        ============
Task 1              USD0.00
    Resource 1      USD100.00
    Resource 2      USD120.00
Task 2              USD0.00
    Resource 3      USD150.00
```

I would like to access the value of **Billing Rate** in VBA Macro. But since it is a custom field at task level, I am unable to access it in assignment object in Task.Assignments.

I tried

```
Assignment.Resource.GetField(FieldNameToFieldConstant("Billing Rate"))
```

But getting error:

```
<The argument is not valid.>
```

How do I access this field at the assignment level?

On a related note, the field can be accessed in PowerBI under Assignment table at "BillingRate_T", but unable to access in Project VBA Macro. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looking at [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/a5cc1945-38f5-4917-a3ea-511d0a11e951/ms-project-vba-assignments-and-custom-fields?forum=project2010custprog) (scroll to the very bottom...) it seems a solution would be to figure out which Enterprise field is used for "Billing Rate" and query that directly. For example: `Assignment.EnterpriseNumber1`

Comment: Thank you, but the those enterprise fields (e.g. EnterpriseCost1 - EnterpriseCost10) actually show up in watch window, and those are not custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

If the Billing Rate figures are already input as the standard rate for each resource on the resource sheet, you could use the following on a task-by-task basis:

```
Sub testBR()
Dim t As Task
Dim res As Resource
Dim asg As Assignment
Dim aN, br As String
Set t = ActiveSelection.Tasks(1)
For Each asg In t.Assignments
aN = asg.ResourceName
For Each res In ActiveProject.Resources
    If res.Name = aN Then
    br = res.StandardRate
    'do something with the 'br' variable before it is overwritten
    Debug.Print br
    End If
Next res
Next asg
End Sub
```

Another method using foreground processing, going task-by-task could be:

```
Sub testBR1()
'start on the task name
Dim aBR As String
aBR = SelectTaskField(1, "Cost1 (Billing Rate)", True) 'change the reference column as needed
aBR = ActiveCell
'do something with the 'aBR' variable before it is overwritten
Debug.Print aBR
End Sub
```